# R control over number of consecutive NA values per row of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, na, missing-data

There are similarly worded questions, but not quite what I'm looking to do.

I have a data frame where I'd like to remove rows that have n number of consecutive NA values.

```
1   Manhattan   NA      2300    NA      2275    2300    
2   Manhattan   2999    2975    NA      NA      2995    
3   Manhattan   NA      NA      NA      NA      4400    
4   Manhattan   6725    6500    6750    6995    6800    
5   Brooklyn    2000    1995    1975    2000    1999    
6   Bronx       1200    3200    NA      NA      NA
```

I have some working code that removes n number of total NA values, but would like to tweak it for consecutive.

```
delete.na <- function(df, n=0) {
  df[rowSums(is.na(df)) <= n,]
}
df <- delete.na(df,3)
```

So, in this case after removing rows with 3 consecutive NA values I would have:

```
1   Manhattan   NA      2300    NA      2275    2300    
2   Manhattan   2999    2975    NA      NA      2995    
4   Manhattan   6725    6500    6750    6995    6800    
5   Brooklyn    2000    1995    1975    2000    1999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to loop over the rows, check with `rle` to return the list of values and lengths of adjacent elements that are same (here it is the logical vector (`is.na` - i.e. TRUE - for NA and FALSE for non-NA), as the 'values' are logical, use that to subset the 'lengths', check if it is `all` less than 3 and use that as row index to subset rows

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(with(rle(is.na(x)), lengths[values]) <3)),]
#     city col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1 Manhattan   NA 2300   NA 2275 2300
#2 Manhattan 2999 2975   NA   NA 2995
#4 Manhattan 6725 6500 6750 6995 6800
#5  Brooklyn 2000 1995 1975 2000 1999
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("Manhattan", "Manhattan", "Manhattan", 
"Manhattan", "Brooklyn", "Bronx"), col1 = c(NA, 2999L, NA, 6725L, 
2000L, 1200L), col2 = c(2300L, 2975L, NA, 6500L, 1995L, 3200L
), col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 6750L, 1975L, NA), col4 = c(2275L, NA, 
NA, 6995L, 2000L, NA), col5 = c(2300L, 2995L, 4400L, 6800L, 1999L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```